# Fire workflow with infopath button, without submitting form?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, infopath, custom-form

Afternoon all,

Background: I have a custom list which I exported from 2007, and imported into 2010 and then rebuilt the form with Infopath 2010. This form has the ability to select from a dropdown of multiple potential emails which are auto-populated based on the entries in the form (they are all templates used to engage other groups). Currently, I have a button which can be pressed in the form directly from a browser which will submit the form to the main data connection - thus firing the workflow.

Problem: When you press that button, you have to close the form and open it again to make any modifications because you will get a save conflict error if you try to modify and save again.

Question: Is there a way to add a button which will allow me to directly fire a workflow from the infopath browser form, without saving the entry?

I have done quite a bit of research and have found some solutions, but none of them take into consideration the save conflict that will arise after submitting, and then attempting to edit the form again.

Answer (score 0):

Okay there are a couple things going on in your problem:

1) It will unfortunately be impossible to kick off a workflow without saving the data, as the workflow will not have any form information to run off of. If the form is not saved, the entered data does not exist anywhere (except in that one browser waiting to be saved).

2) I am going to guess that you are not running into a save conflict because of your InfoPath form, but rather because your workflow is actually modifying the form in question. This *will* cause a save conflict, as the open form is no longer the most recent version since somebody else (the workflow) edited the item.

If my guess for point 2 is correct, there might be a workaround for your problem. Add a second button on the form that says "Refresh form" and have it run the action "Query for data" from the main connection. Let people know that they should wait a second to let the workflow run, then click this button to retrieve any changes from the workflow before proceeding and editing the form again.